# Asp & Google Map Api: Show location to asp:textbox through google.maps.event.addListener

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-maps-api-3

I want to put the coordinates of the marker to an asp:textbox but when the button is pressed (this triggers the function to transfer data to textbox) it doesn't show, also it should be an asp: textbox so I can use validation to it.

this is my code

script to load map

```
    var latitude;
    var longitude;
    function initMap() {
        var mapDiv = document.getElementById('map');
        var map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, {
            center: { lat: 6.499767, lng: 124.844858 },
            zoom: 18
        });

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: { lat: 6.499767, lng: 124.844858 },
            draggable: true,
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
            map: map,
            title: 'Drag me to your address pls.'
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "dragend", function (event) {
            latitude = this.position.lat();
            longitude = this.position.lng();
        });

        marker.setMap(map);
    }

</script>
```

Script function to pass to asp textbox

```
 <script>
    var name;
    function transferdata() {

        $(document).ready(function () {
            document.getElementById('<%=txt_coord.ClientID %>').Text = latitude + "," + longitude;
                });
            };

</script>
```

MapDiv is inside a ModalPopup

```
<cc1:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender2" TargetControlID="HiddenField1" runat="server" PopupControlID="Panel2" CancelControlID="btn_map_ok" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground"></cc1:ModalPopupExtender>

<asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server" CssClass="modalPopup" align="center" Width="80%" Style="display: none">
    <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/icons/cancel.png" CssClass=" pull-right" Width="30px" />
    <h3>Drag the red pin to your address.</h3>
    <p class="text-center small alert-warning">
        Note:<br />
        If you have trouble finding your address, switch the map style to satellite or vice versa.
        <br />
        You can also zoom in or out the map, and/or enable street view.
        <br />
    </p>
    <div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 400px;">
    </div>

    <input id="btn_map_ok" name="btn_map_ok" runat="server" type="button" value="OK" style="margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;" class="center-block btn-primary btn-sm" onclick="transferdata();" />
</asp:Panel>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your javascript method as below. document.ready only fires when document loaded completely. after buttong click there is no use of calling this. use .value instead of .Text to update value in text box.

```
<script>
var name;
function transferdata() {
    alert("This is a Message!");
    document.getElementById('<%=txt_coord.ClientID %>').value = latitude + "," + longitude;

    document.getElementById('<%=txt_coord.ClientID %>').value = latitude + "," + longitude;
};

</script>
```